# angular cli 6, ng test not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I have just updated my angular project to angular 6.

ng build and ng serve work, but when I run my tests with the command:

```
ng test
```

I get the output:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" should have required property 'tsConfig'.
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
],
"mapRoot": "./",
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 30):

I solved it. Somehow when I upgraded the project to Angular 6 the `tsConfig` key was missing under test -> options in `angular.json`.

Comment: As per the other answer, this is the default setting for tsConfig  =>   "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json"

Answer (score 21):

for me

1. in file: angular.json
2. at json node path: projects->{{yourProjectName}}->architect->test->options
3. add node: "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json"

Comment: this answer is also correct but it is not much descriptive . So, its a bit tricky to understand.

Comment: yeah....there is tsConfig in build as well as in test options...you gotta add this to the test options

Comment: Shouldnt it be the `src/tsconfig.spec.json` file that you have to add to the `test` section?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem but it turned out to be due to **polyfills.ts** being added to the **tsconfig.spec.json**,
Polyfills was importing core-js/es7/reflect and I was also doing the same in the **src/test.ts** removing the import from src/test.ts fixed my issue

Comment: which line you exaclty removed